# Data is not getting shown in select tag

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, select

I have a select tag of chapters , I am loading a result from query in it. But its not showing in a select tag, the chapter names are displayed like echo statements.

```
     <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>MCQ Questions</title>

</head>
<body>

<?php
session_start();

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=174.75.54;dbname=handbook', 'airman', 'airman'); 

    $type = $_POST['type'];
    $question = $_POST["question"];
    $optionA = $_POST["opt1"];
    $optionB = $_POST["opt2"];
    $optionC = $_POST["opt3"];
    $optionD = $_POST["opt4"];
    $ans = $_POST["ans"];
    $chapter = $_POST["chapter"];
?>

<form method="post" action="mcq.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">


<?php if(isset($_POST['question']))
{
?>

Enter the question: <input name="question" type="text" value = "<?php echo $question?>"</input> <br><br>
<?php
}
else
{
?>
    <p> Enter the question :</p> <input name="question" type="text"></input> <br><br>

<?php
}
?>

Select rank : 

<select name="type" id="type" onchange="this.form.submit()"> 

<?php if(isset($_POST['type']))
{ ?>
<option value="1"  <?php echo($type==1?"selected":"");?>>SSgt</option> 

<option value="2"  <?php echo($type==2?"selected":"");?>>TSgt</option> 
<option value="3" <?php echo($type==3?"selected":"");?>>MSgt</option>
</select>
<?php
}
    else 
    {
    ?>
    <option value="1">SSgt</option> 
<option value="2">TSgt</option> 
<option value="3">MSgt</option> 
</select>
    <?php
    }
    ?>

<br><br>
<?php if(isset($_POST['opt1']))
{ ?>
<p> Enter options :</p>
Enter option A : <input name="opt1" type="text" value = "<?php echo $optionA?>"</input> <br><br>

<?php
}
else{
?>
<p> Enter options :</p>
Enter option A : <input name="opt1" type="text"> <br><br>
<?php   
}
?>
<?php if(isset($_POST['opt2']))
{ ?>

Enter option B : <input name="opt2" value = "<?php echo $optionB?>"</input> <br><br>

<?php
}
else{
?>
Enter option B : <input name="opt2" type="text"> <br><br>
<?php   
}
?>

<?php if(isset($_POST['opt3']))
{ ?>
Enter option C : <input name="opt3" value = "<?php echo $optionC?>"</input> <br><br>

<?php
}
else{
?>

Enter option C : <input name="opt3" type="text"> <br><br>

<?php
}
?>

<?php if(isset($_POST['opt4']))
{ ?>
Enter option D : <input name="opt4" value = "<?php echo $optionD?>"</input> <br><br>
<?php
}
else{
?>

Enter option D : <input name="opt4" type="text"> <br><br>

<?php
}
?>


Select correct answer :

<select name="ans" id="type"> 


<?php if(isset($_POST['ans']))
{
?>
<option value="A"  <?php echo($ans==A?"selected":"");?>>A</option> 

<option value="B"  <?php echo($ans==B?"selected":"");?>>B</option> 

<option value="C" <?php echo($ans==C?"selected":"");?>>C</option>

<option value="D" <?php echo($ans==D?"selected":"");?>>D</option
</select>

<br><br>
<?php
}
else
{
?>

<option value="A">A</option> 
<option value="B">B</option> 
<option value="C">C</option> 
<option value="D">D</option>
</select>
<?php
}
?>
<br><br>

Select Chapter : 
<select name="chapters" id="chapters"> 

<?php 

if(isset($_POST['type']))
{
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM chapters where type = :type"); 
    $stmt->bindParam("type", $type);
$stmt->execute(); 
$results = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

if(count($results > 0)){ 
foreach($results as $row):?> 
<option value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['title'];?></option> 
<?php 
endforeach; 
}else{?> 

<option value="0">No data found</option> 
<?php 
} 

}

else{

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM chapters where type = 1"); 

$stmt->execute(); 
$results = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

if(count($results > 0)){ 
foreach($results as $row):?> 
<option value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['title'];?></option> 
<?php 
endforeach; 
}else{?> 

<option value="0">No data found</option> 
<?php 
} 
}
?> 

</select> <br><br>

<input type="Submit" value = "Submit" name="b1">

<?php

if(isset($_POST['b1']))
{

ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(1); 
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); 

$type = $_POST['type'];
$question = $_POST['question'];
$optionA = $_POST['opt1'];
$optionB = $_POST['opt2'];
$optionC = $_POST['opt3'];
$optionD = $_POST['opt4'];
$ans = $_POST['ans'];
$chapter = $_POST['chapters']; 

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO questions (question,answer_a,answer_b,answer_c,answer_d,answer,type,chapterId) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?)");
$stmt->execute(array($question, $optionA, $optionB, $optionC, $optionD, $ans,$type,$chapter));

if ($dbh->lastInsertId())
{   
    echo 'Question submitted.';

    echo '<a href="mcq.php">Upload another question.</a>';
    session_destroy();
}
else
{
    echo 'Question could not submit.';
}
}
?>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

It loads the data in select tag 1st time if type is not set, but if the type is set it shows chapters like echo statements.

What is wrong here? Please help thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I build my options in php then echo the whole string like this
in php

```
IF ($row[$i]['abc'] == 'A'){
$a[$i]='<option value="A" selected="selected">A</option>';
$b[$i]='<option value="B" >B</option>';
}
IF ($row[$i]['abc'] == 'B'){
$a[$i]='<option value="A" >A</option>';
$b[$i]='<option value="B" selected="selected" B</option>';
}
```

in my html

```
 <select>
    <php? echo $a[$i]; ?>
    <php? echo $b[$i]; ?>
 </select>
```

always work and sets it on right data

for practice and learning create a file called try1.php

```
<?php

$1='<option value="1">1</option>';
$2='<option value="2">2</option>';
//name of your selection
if(isset($_POST['1']){
echo 'you selected : '.$_post['1'];

}
?>
<html>
<body>
<select name="1">
<?php echo $1; ?>
<?php echo $2; ?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="1" value="1">
</body>
</html>
```

this is code from a file i made for my wife and it has worked for 2 years but it very old and doesnt have function to get what is selected

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("../staffpage/getstaff.php");
include_once("../staffpage/staffheader.php");
include_once("../cert/dbc.php");
?>
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
      <body>
        <h1>&#20250;&#21592;&#27880;&#20876;</h1>

       <form action="direct to you php file handling your indput.php" method="post">
          <tr>
             <td>
                <table width="60%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                 <tr>
                    <td colspan="3"><strong>&#20250;&#21592;&#27880;&#20876;</strong></td>
                 </tr>
                  <tr>
             <td width="78">&#21345;&#21495;</td>
         <td width="6">:</td>

         <td width="294"><input type="text" name="cno" required/></td>
         </tr>
         <td width="78"> &#25910;&#25454;&#21495;</td>
         <td width="6">:
         </td>

         <td width="294"><input type="text" name="rno" required/></td>

         </td>
         </tr>
         <td width="78"> &#22995;&#21517;</td>
         <td width="6">:</td>
         <td width="294"><input type="text" name="fname" required/></td>
         </tr>


         <td width="78">&#30005;&#35805;</td>
         <td width="6">:</td>
         <td width="294"><input type="text" name="ctel" required/></td>
         </tr>


         <td width="78"> cardname </td>
         <td width="6">:</td>
         <td width="294">
         <select name="cardnameno" >
            <?php
                //my query in this file
                include_once("../sec/cards.php");
                $i=0;
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                $z2=$row['cardname'];
                $z1=$row['cardnameno'];
                ?>

            <option value="<?php echo $row['cardnameno']; ?>" ><?php echo $row['name']; ?></option>
            <?php
            $i++;
            }
            ?>  
        </select>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form></p>
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
</html>
```

i include this file in another but should not stop it from working

Comment: How can I implement this in my code? I am using only one php file.

Comment: also using only 1 file but you must remember until you post code in isset($_post won't run also in <select name=what name you choose"> also if use isset _POST your form action should be action="" because it post to itself

Comment: sorry I am not getting it, I am using this.submit(); to submit the form, and checking the _POST['type'] if it is set or not.

Comment: nothing happens on click of button after selecting the option in trial code.I changed $1,$2 to variable $A and $B that was not accepted.